# When I scroll listview, values get changed

Tags: android

I have set some conditions for my text views, but when I scroll my list view, some values and later all of them, change status and meet the condition even though 9 is not equal to 5.

what should I do?

p.s.: i tried two different ways for setting conditions

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        if (row == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.NUMER1=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lin11);
            layoutHandler.NUMER2=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lin12);
            layoutHandler.NUMER3=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lin13);
            row.setTag(layoutHandler);
        }

    else {
            layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler)row.getTag();
        }

    DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider)this.getItem(position);
    layoutHandler.NUMER1.setText(dataProvider.getNum1());
    layoutHandler.NUMER2.setText(dataProvider.getNum2());
    layoutHandler.NUMER3.setText(dataProvider.getNum3());

    String equalll = "5";

    if (layoutHandler.NUMER1.getText().toString().equals(equalll)){
        layoutHandler.NUMER1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    if (dataProvider.getNum2().equals(equalll)) {
        layoutHandler.NUMER2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    if (dataProvider.getNum3().equals(koti)) {
        layoutHandler.NUMER3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    return row;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also set text color to your `TextView`s even when not meeting condition because `View`s are recycled in `ListView`. This means that your previously set text color will show up in another item even if condition is not met.

Make the following edit to your code.

```
if (layoutHandler.NUMER1.getText().toString().equals(equalll)){
    layoutHandler.NUMER1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
} else {
    layoutHandler.NUMER1.setColor(YOUR_DEFAULT_COLOR);
}

if (dataProvider.getNum2().equals(equalll)) {
    layoutHandler.NUMER2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
} else {
    layoutHandler.NUMER2.setColor(YOUR_DEFAULT_COLOR);
}

if (dataProvider.getNum3().equals(koti)) {
    layoutHandler.NUMER3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
} else {
    layoutHandler.NUMER3.setColor(YOUR_DEFAULT_COLOR);
}
```